# How to mitigate local network problem with Expo

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth, expo

Expo is crashing when using an Android emulator on my Ubuntu machine. So what I want to do is upload the app to my real Android device using Expo. But when I do this using the local wifi network, I get:

[image]

[image]

Perhaps I should just physically tether my phone to my Ubuntu laptop instead of going through Wifi? What about bluetooth to upload the app to the phone from my Ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the tutorial there is an explanation of how to handle this: https://docs.expo.io/get-started/create-a-new-app/

> **Is the app not loading on your device?**
>
> First, make sure that you are on the same wifi network on your computer and your device.
>
> If it still doesn't work, it may be due to the router configuration — this is common for public networks. You can work around this by choosing the "Tunnel" connection type in Expo Dev Tools, then scanning the QR code again.
>
> Using the "Tunnel" connection type will make app reloads considerably slower than on "LAN" or "Local", so it's best to avoid tunnel when possible. You may want to install a simulator/emulator to speed up development if "Tunnel" is required for accessing your machine from another device on your network.

An aside -- I've opened an issue [here](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/2050) to discuss adding an easy and fast way to connect to your device under these circumstances.